# Maven: Remove last version when deploy

Tags: maven, deployment

Is there a way to remove the last version of a release in an artifact repository when deploy the new version? I mean, imagine that I have deployed version 1.0.0 of com.company.project:project. If I deploy version 1.1.0 of the same artifact, I'd want that version 1.0.0 was deleted. Sorry if it is obvious, I'm newbie in this...

Comment: It's generally not good practice to remove deployed versions... is this action completely necessary?

Comment: Thanks for replying. It isn't completely necessary and it isn't in a production environment. I'd just like to know if it is possible since I am testing how deployments works.

Comment: I am not aware of a built-in way to do that, but you could certainly add a workflow step that will delete the folder outside of maven's goals, but I wouldn't rely on that. If it's not production, I would just do it by hand.

Comment: I have deployed my artifacts in a Bitbucket repo, so I can't remove  it by hand like I'd do in Nexus repo.